# Confused with simple assembly code (IA32)

Tags: c, assembly, translation

Consider the following C functions :

```
void f1(int i) 
{ 
    int j=i+a; 
}

int f2(int i) 
{
    return i+a; 
}
```

and their translation (given by instructor) in assembly language :

```
#f1 translation :

subl $8, %esp 
movl 12(%esp), %eax 
movl %eax, 4(%esp) 
movl 4(%esp), %eax 
addl a, %eax 
movl %eax, (%esp) 
addl $8, %esp 
ret

#f2 translation :

subl $8, %esp 
movl 12(%esp), %eax 
movl %eax, 4(%esp) 
movl a, %eax 
movl %eax, (%esp) 
movl (%esp), %eax 
addl 4(%esp), %eax 
addl $8, %esp 
ret
```

I've tried to draw and write down each step of the two assembly code but I simply cannot see how the two lead to different C codes.

By convention, the register **%eax** contains the **returned value** of the function. If I'm not mistaken, the register **%eax** contains the value **(i+a)** at the end of **BOTH** assembly code although **f1** **returns nothing**.

***1) Why's that? What exactly tells that a function is returning a value?***

Also, in both codes, we have two lines like this two :

```
movl %eax, (%esp) 
movl (%esp), %eax
```

the last one seems to be redundant, ***2) or isn't it?***

Comment: To put it simple: you are mistaken. `f1` does not return anything, because you **don't** return anything. There is no `return` statement therefore you don't return anything. It's as simple as that. Even if `%eax` always returns the return value, the return value of `f1` will stay `void`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the ABI says `EAX` contains the return value, functions that return something will have the return value there. If a function does not return anything, the register may contain whatever. In this case it might be the same value, I didn't read the code.

If the calling function doesn't read the return value it doesn't matter what that register contains. So it is all about the caller and the called function. They must obay the ABI. If a void function is called, the calling code will never try to use that register as anything.

So nothing in the assembly code says the function returns something. It's all in the C code.

As for 2, the `MOV` is redundant. It is because you didn't compile with optimizations so the compiler will just output whatever simple things it wants and is very much not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to understand the difference if you look at compiler output with optimizations enabled:

[gcc 5.3 with `-O3 -m32` on the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc++-O3+-Wall+-fverbose-asm+-m32+-march%3Dhaswell',source:'int+a+%3D+1234%3B++//+global,+not+static+or+const,+so+it+has+to+get+loaded+from+memory%0A%0Avoid+f1(int+i)+%0A%7B+%0A++++int+j%3Di%2Ba%3B+%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+f2(int+i)+%0A%7B%0A++++return+i%2Ba%3B+%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3):

```
int a = 1234;  // global, not static or const, so it has to get loaded from memory

void f1(int i) { int j=i+a; }
// 3 : warning: unused variable 'j' [-Wunused-variable]
    ret

int f2(int i) { return i+a; }
    movl    a, %eax         # load a
    addl    4(%esp), %eax   # add i from its arg-passing location on the stack
    ret
```

`f1` is optimized away completely, because it has no externally-visible effects (no return value and no side-effects).  Local variables disappear (go out of scope) when a function returns, so there's no need to compute it at all.  (Since it's not `volatile`)

Probably your prof was trying to illustrate how locals are stored on the stack.  (What C calls "automatic" storage, as opposed to dynamic (malloc) or static (globals and `static`).)

`gcc -O0` is too noisy to be a good illustration of that, esp. the way it copies args from above the return address to locals.

`gcc -O0` mostly just translates each C statement directly to asm, without considering the rest of the function.  And also, variables are stored / reloaded between statements, instead of staying live in registers.  (Except sometimes they do stay live as part of a large expression).

`gcc -Og` is only slightly optimized, and corresponds to the source fairly well.  It does still optimize `f1` to an empty function.  So does `-O1`.

Comment: I'm the upvote, but the instructor might be attempting to teach his students how parameters are passed onto the stack and how to access them that way. It would also be an opportunity to learn how to place data onto the stack as local variables. Using the stack may not be obvious to new assembler developers, but using examples of parameter passing on the stack (and local variable on the stack) may be a baby step towards student learning. I can see a reasonable argument for a professor doing this.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: raw `gcc -O0` output is too braindead to be a good illustration of how to do that.  The OP didn't seem to know that it was compiler output, just that the prof gave it to them.  If I was handing out code, I'd hand out hand-written asm that reserved space on the stack and stored variables there, but not code that copied the stack-arg to a local and crap like that.  `gcc -O0` is hard to understand, because it's longer, and because it leaves you wondering if there's a reason for the stores/reloads (e.g. is the register still "live", or is memory now the only copy?)

Comment: If I were a professor, I'd be going through progressions. Depending on what I was trying to achieve, I still think it is valuable as is. In fact I'd want my students to wonder about the excessive load/stores. In a followup assignment I'd ask them to modify the code to only use the stack for parameter passing but remove unnecessary code. The excessive load stores are still doing the intended functionality. Students should be able to trace through the mess. If they can't trace even that bloated output then there are serious problems.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I feel like it's not hard, just time-consuming and not very informative.  But I don't teach classes.  I feel like I can trace it pretty quickly only because I'm used to that kind of pattern from compiler output, and I can take a guess at what it's doing.  If it looked like un-optimized compiler output but had one instruction different, I might not notice.  Maybe the prof told the class it was un-optimized compiler output but the OP missed it?  Handing out that code without the clue that it's intentionally bad is the part that I object to.